# Bigcommerce Custom Product Builder with real time preview

Tags: bigcommerce

My client is interested in having a custom made product builder app on Bigcommerce. This app should let users to build their custom made jacket. They can choose for example, colour of the jacket, zip colour, button styles, etc.

And a product preview will be shown according to the above selected opinions INSTANTLY, so that the end user will know how the final product will looks like.

I know that there is an app on Shopify by Boldapps - [Product Builder](https://apps.shopify.com/product-builder), and here is one of the example by them: http://goodvibecases.com/collections/custom-cases/products/iphone-6

Is this possible on Bigcommerce? Thanks

Arnold Chan